# Regex for detecting a query string

Tags: regex, posix

I'm trying to use regex for testing a URL.

- accepted cases:

  ```
  www.mystite.com/whatever/?bla=dfgsd&page=test 
  www.mystite.com/whatever/?bla=dfgsd&page=test&
  www.mystite.com/whatever/?bla=dfgsd&page=test&hello=bla 
  www.mystite.com/whatever/?page=test&hello=bla
  ```
- rejected:

  ```
  www.mystite.com/whatever/?hello=bla&page=testfff 
  www.mystite.com/whatever/?page=testfff&hello=bla - NOT good
  ```

because misses **`&page=test&`**, **`page=test&`** or **`&page=test`**

That's what I tried, and it doesn't work:

```
([^&amp;]+)([page=test])([^&amp;]+)
```

You can ignore the domain and sub folder, what I'm trying to check is only after the question mark

Comment: Please provide some rules you want to express using regex. The examples you have given are not self-explanatory. Also would you mind explaining the regex you've tried. I can't imagine what it's supposed to do.

Comment: And your attempt has some very basic beginner errors. Don't use square brackets if you don't know what they do.  See the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag wiki](/tags/regex/info) for some basic troubleshooting tips.

Comment: My string can contain: &page=test, &page=test&, page=test&, but not: &page=test[whatever], &page=test[whatever]&, page=test[whatever]&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the question for the 3rd time I think I now get what you are asking for:

```
&?page=test($|&)
```

This matches all occurences of "page=test" with optional "&" at the start. At the end there needs to be either an "&" (optionally followed by other characters) or nothing (end of string).

Does this solve your problem?